# How to change the title bar icon using winapi

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I have made an application using Windows API and have used the resource folder to change the icon to a custom one I made. Now the program is using my icon on the desktop however in the title bar there is the default icon, this one to be exact.[image: Default Icon]

Now how am I suppose to change it to my custom icon?
I am using MSVC++

```
WNDCLASS wndclass;

wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;


hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,
    TEXT("Random"),
    WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    300,
    120,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL);
```

Comment: Please post the code you're using that calls `CreateWindow` / `CreateWindowEx`.

Comment: Is this a pure WinAPI program, or are you using a framework such as MFC?

Comment: No framework MFC or Qt or anything. It's just pure WinAPI

Comment: As a note you can use `L"Random"` instead of calling `TEXT()`.  That function converts from `char` to wide characters, adding the L prefix to a constant does the same also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use `RegisterClassEx` to register your window class, the `WNDCLASSEX` structure has a `hIconSm` field that lets you specify a small icon. If you go this way, don't forget to also initialize the `cbSize` field.

Alternatively, you can assign a small icon to a window after creation using the `WM_SETICON` message.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was trying to accomplish.