# How to change icon in wix installer which is coming along with the product name

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I have a wix installer where on top left i can see a setup icon. Is there possibility of changing this icon

[image]

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think there's an easy way to do this. Maybe using a custom action on each dialog and [using the Windows API to set the small icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131356/how-to-change-the-title-bar-icon-using-winapi) (?).

Comment: Trying to find alternative other then custom action. But thanks lurker. will check custom action option as well

Comment: I found [this interesting post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.platformsdk.msi/my-l5UZ1d1A), which states, *The icon that you see is the icon of `msiexec.exe`. It comes from the file extension association. If you like to change association it will be changed for all files having `.msi` extension...*. So a custom action, to avoid changing it for all `.msi` files under file association settings, might be the only choice.

Comment: Thanks lurker. So this basically is a associated icon of .msi file. I am using C# in a .net framework 3.5 application. Can somebody help me custom action code in C# to change the icon.

Comment: The link in my first comment shows how to set the icon for a given window (not change the file association icon), which I think is what you would prefer here (?).

Comment: I am looking for the solution to change icons on all the setup screen come in the installation.Just for my setup file. I don't wanted to change the association for .msi file in general. That code looks like c++. i am working in C#

Comment: The code I linked to is C++, but the Windows API principles are the same. You should be able to study what it does and just do similar actions in C#.

Comment: Thanks Lurker. I will try check it