# How to create a HICON from base64?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I am converting a picture from a base64 string into an `HICON` that could work when registering a new class:

```cpp
WNDCLASSEX wc{};
wc.hIcon = < here >;
```

I got the `base64_decode()` function here: [base64.cpp](https://github.com/ReneNyffenegger/cpp-base64)

```cpp
#include <windows.h> // GDI includes.
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")
    
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
        
std::string base64 = "......";
std::string decodedImage = base64_decode(base64);

DWORD imageSize = decodedImage.length();
HGLOBAL hMem = ::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, imageSize);
LPVOID pImage = ::GlobalLock(hMem);
memcpy(pImage, decodedImage.c_str(), imageSize);

IStream* pStream = NULL;
::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hMem, FALSE, &pStream);

Gdiplus::Image image(pStream);

int wd = image.GetWidth();
int hgt = image.GetHeight();
auto format = image.GetPixelFormat();

Bitmap* bmp = new Bitmap(wd, hgt, format);
auto gg = std::unique_ptr<Graphics>(Graphics::FromImage(bmp));
gg->Clear(Color::Transparent);
gg->DrawImage(image, 0, 0, wd, hgt);

...
```

I couldn't find a way to get the `HICON` from the `Image`, so I was trying to convert the `Image` to `Bitmap`.

I'm getting these two errors on the line `gg->DrawImage(image, 0, 0, wd, hgt);`

> C2664 'Gdiplus::Status Gdiplus::Graphics::DrawImage(Gdiplus::Image *,Gdiplus::REAL,Gdiplus::REAL,Gdiplus::REAL,Gdiplus::REAL)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Gdiplus::Image' to 'Gdiplus::Image *'
>
> E0304 no instance of overloaded function "Gdiplus::Graphics::DrawImage" matches the argument list

Comment: Your code can't be compiled. All statements must be in a function.

Comment: Why are you focused on the last error, that comes from the first one? You should fix the first error. How to fix errors like `cannot convert Type to Type*` is obvious.

Comment: Related: Windows has already base64 capabilities: [CryptBinaryToStringW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptbinarytostringw) and [CryptStringToBinary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptstringtobinaryw)

Comment: @273K it can be obvious to you, if it were to me i wasn't asking here

Comment: Just trust, rare SO user want to answer very basic questions. Especially if OP does not make effort to read books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cannot convert argument 1 from 'Gdiplus::Image' to 'Gdiplus::Image *'

`DrawImage()` expects a *pointer* to an `Image` object, but you are passing it the actual object instead.

Change this statement:

```
gg->DrawImage(image, 0, 0, wd, hgt);
```

To this instead:

```
gg->DrawImage(&image, 0, 0, wd, hgt); // <-- note the added '&' ...
```

Comment: Thank you, Remy! Do you know to decode the b64 string using the winapi mentioned in comments before, so i wouldn't need external libs?

Comment: @nat [`CryptStringToBinaryA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptstringtobinarya) does that. Just make sure to call the ANSI version, since base64 is assumed to be encoded as ASCII.

Comment: @IInspectable A unicode string can hold base64 just fine. What is important is that base64 encodes binary data into ASCII characters, and both `CryptStringToBinaryA()` and `CryptStringToBinaryW()` can parse those ASCII characters to output binary data. So the input string can be in either ANSI (`char`) or Unicode (`wchar_t`) format. But since the code in question is storing the base64 in a `std::string`, then yes, `CryptStringToBinaryA()` would be appropriate.

Comment: @Nathan that is a completely separate question, unrelated to this post's question about getting an `HICON` from an `Image`. You should ask the base64 question as a new post.

Comment: Thank you Remy, `wc.hIcon = hIcon;` is changing only the icon at the taskbar, how to also change the icon in the caption?

Comment: @Nathan again, you are asking multiple questions that are not related to each other. How to obtain the `HICON` itself (the subject of this post), and how to use the `HICON` for various tasks (the subject of other posts), are separate topics. Each new question should be a separate post. But please, do search for existing questions first, for instance [How to change the title bar icon using winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131356/).