# How to decode a picture converted to base64 using CryptStringToBinary?

Tags: c++, winapi

My doubt is about how to use the value returned by the API to reconstruct the image.

Also, does the way I'm creating the `Bitmap` preserve the picture transparency?

```
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

LPCWSTR base64 = L"";

DWORD dwSkip;
DWORD dwFlags;
DWORD dwDataLen;

CryptStringToBinary(
    base64,
    _tcslen(base64),
    CRYPT_STRING_BASE64,
    NULL,
    &dwDataLen,
    &dwSkip,
    &dwFlags);

DWORD imageSize = dwDataLen;
HGLOBAL hMem = ::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, imageSize);
LPVOID pImage = ::GlobalLock(hMem);
memcpy(pImage, ???? , imageSize);

IStream* pStream = NULL;
::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hMem, FALSE, &pStream);

Gdiplus::Image image(pStream);

image.GetWidth();

int wd = image.GetWidth();
int hgt = image.GetHeight();
auto format = image.GetPixelFormat();

Bitmap* bmp = new Bitmap(wd, hgt, format);
auto gg = std::unique_ptr<Graphics>(Graphics::FromImage(bmp));
gg->Clear(Color::Transparent);
gg->DrawImage(&image, 0, 0, wd, hgt);

HICON hIcon;
bmp->GetHICON(&hIcon);

pStream->Release();
GlobalUnlock(hMem);
GlobalFree(hMem);

wc.hIcon = hIcon;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "picture string"?

Comment: You need to check the `HRESULT` returned from `CreateStreamOnHGlobal`.

Comment: What is b64? Please use the correct terminology or define the used terms.

Comment: Since you're not actually writing the base64-decoded data *anywhere*, I'm going to go ahead and say what you have so far isn't going to work (yet). If you're using `CryptStringToBinary` to calculate the required size info, it needs to be called *twice* (once to calculate the size, once to actual do the conversion after allocating the sized memory).

Comment: Using a `wchar_t` string to store base64 seems to me as a complete nonsense, since b definition base64 onl uses ASCII characters.

Comment: My doubt is about it `Since you're not actually writing the base64-decoded data anywhere`, on how to get/write the decoded data.

Comment: I have no doubts about you not actually writing the base64 decoded data anyway; I'm *certain* that you're not. Read the documentation of [CryptStringToBinary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptstringtobinarya). The pattern of call-twice (first to get the size requirements, use that size data to allocate memory, then second call to do the actual operation and storage) is used in *many* places within the Windows API. May as well become familiar with it.

Comment: @Nathan "*Also, does the way I'm creating the Bitmap preserve the picture transparency?*" - that is a separate question not related to base64 decoding. This is a Q&A site, so please, only 1 question per post, per StackOverflow guidelines. Post the transparency issue as a new question, or as as edit to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73345926/) since it is related that that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My doubt is about how to use the value returned by the API to reconstruct the image.

You are calling `CryptStringToBinary()` only 1 time, to *calculate the size* of the decoded bytes.  You are even *allocating memory* to receive the decoded bytes.  But, you are not actually decoding the base64 string to *produce* the bytes.  You need to call `CryptStringToBinary()` a second time for that, eg:

```
LPCWSTR base64 = L"...";    

DWORD dwStrLen = static_cast<DWORD>(wcslen(base64)); // or: 0
DWORD dwDataLen = 0;

if (!CryptStringToBinaryW(
    base64,
    dwStrLen,
    CRYPT_STRING_BASE64,
    NULL,
    &dwDataLen,
    NULL,
    NULL))
{
    // error handling...
}
    
HGLOBAL hMem = ::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, dwDataLen);
if (!hMem)
{
    // error handling...
}

LPVOID pImage = ::GlobalLock(hMem);
    
if (!CryptStringToBinaryW(
    base64,
    dwStrLen,
    CRYPT_STRING_BASE64,
    (BYTE*) pImage,
    &dwDataLen,
    NULL,
    NULL))
{
    // error handling...
}

::GlobalUnlock(hMem);

// use hMem as needed...

::GlobalFree(hMem);
```

Comment: `argument of type "LPVOID" is incompatible with parameter of type "BYTE *"` in the second call to `CryptStringToBinaryW`

Comment: @Nathan updated my example. Just typecast the pointer

Comment: Remy, compiler is saying `warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'DWORD', possible loss of data` in the last `NULL` parameter of `CryptStringToBinaryW`, i tried replacing `NULL` to `0` but the warning persists

Comment: @Nathan The last parameter is a `DWORD*` pointer. `NULL` can be safely assigned to *any* pointer. Your **warning** is related to the 2nd parameter, as `wcslen()` returns a `size_t`, which may be larger than `DWORD`, depending on compiler implementation. Unless you are working with strings over 2billion characters, don't worry about it. Just type-cast the warning away: `static_cast<DWORD>(wcslen(base64))`, or else set the parameter to 0, per the documentation: "*[in] `cchString` ... If this parameter is zero, `pszString` is considered to be a null-terminated string.*" I updated my example.

Answer (score 0):

we can use `CreateIconFromResourceEx` instead *gdi++* . example of convert base64 to HICON (assumed that wholea icon file is converted to base64)

```
struct ICONDIRENTRY
{
    BYTE    bWidth;                 // Width of the image
    BYTE    bHeight;                // Height of the image (times 2)
    BYTE    bColorCount;            // Number of colors in image (0 if >=8bpp)
    BYTE    bReserved;              // Reserved
    WORD    wPlanes;                // Color Planes
    WORD    wBitCount;              // Bits per pixel
    DWORD   dwBytesInRes;           // how many bytes in this resource?
    DWORD   dwImageOffset;          // where in the file is this image
};

struct ICONDIR
{
    WORD            NotInFile;      // not in file
    WORD            Reserved;       // Reserved
    WORD            Type;           // resource type (IMAGE_ICON for icons)
    WORD            Count;          // how many images?
    ICONDIRENTRY    Entries[];      // the entries for each image
};

HICON LoadIcon(_In_ ICONDIR* pid, _In_ ULONG cb, _In_ ULONG cxDesired, _In_ ULONG cyDesired)
{
    if (cb < sizeof(ICONDIR) || pid->Type != IMAGE_ICON)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (ULONG Count = pid->Count)
    {
        if (cb < sizeof(ICONDIR) + Count * sizeof(ICONDIRENTRY))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        ICONDIRENTRY* Entry = pid->Entries;
        do 
        {
            if (Entry->bWidth == cxDesired && Entry->bHeight == cyDesired)
            {
                if (Entry->wPlanes != 1)
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                switch (Entry->bColorCount)
                {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 4:
                case 8:
                case 16:
                case 24:
                case 32:
                    break;
                default:
                    return 0;
                }

                DWORD dwImageOffset = Entry->dwImageOffset + FIELD_OFFSET(ICONDIR, Reserved);

                if (cb < dwImageOffset)
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                DWORD dwBytesInRes = Entry->dwBytesInRes;

                if (cb - dwImageOffset < dwBytesInRes)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                return CreateIconFromResourceEx((PBYTE)pid + dwImageOffset, dwBytesInRes, TRUE, 0x00030000, cxDesired, cyDesired, 0);
            }
        } while (Entry++, --Count);
    }

    return 0;
}

HICON LoadIcon(_In_ PSTR psz, _In_ ULONG cch, _In_ int cxDesired, _In_ int cyDesired)
{
    ULONG cb = 0;
    PUCHAR pb = 0;
    PUCHAR buf = 0;

    HICON hi = 0;

    while (CryptStringToBinaryA(psz, cch, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, pb, &cb, 0, 0))
    {
        if (pb)
        {
            hi = LoadIcon((ICONDIR*)buf, cb + FIELD_OFFSET(ICONDIR, Reserved), cxDesired, cyDesired);
            break;
        }

        if (cb < sizeof(ICONDIR))
        {
            break;
        }

        if (!(buf = new UCHAR[cb + FIELD_OFFSET(ICONDIR, Reserved)]))
        {
            break;
        }

        pb = buf + FIELD_OFFSET(ICONDIR, Reserved);
    }
    
    if (buf) delete [] buf;

    return hi;
}
```

for convert icon file to base 64 can use next code:

```
BOOL IsValidIcon(_In_ ICONDIR* pid, _In_ ULONG cb)
{
    if (cb < sizeof(ICONDIR) || pid->Type != IMAGE_ICON)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (ULONG Count = pid->Count)
    {
        if (cb < sizeof(ICONDIR) + Count * sizeof(ICONDIRENTRY))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        ICONDIRENTRY* Entry = pid->Entries;
        do 
        {
            if (Entry->wPlanes != 1)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            switch (Entry->bColorCount)
            {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 4:
            case 8:
            case 16:
            case 24:
            case 32:
                break;
            default:
                return FALSE;
            }

            DWORD dwImageOffset = Entry->dwImageOffset + FIELD_OFFSET(ICONDIR, Reserved);

            if (cb < dwImageOffset)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            DWORD dwBytesInRes = Entry->dwBytesInRes;

            if (cb - dwImageOffset < dwBytesInRes)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

        } while (Entry++, --Count);
    }

    return FALSE;
}

BOOL mi(_In_ PCWSTR lpIconName, _Out_ PSTR* ppsz, _Out_ ULONG* pcch)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(lpIconName, FILE_GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    BOOL f = FALSE;
    FILE_STANDARD_INFO fsi;
    if (GetFileInformationByHandleEx(hFile, FileStandardInfo, &fsi, sizeof(fsi)))
    {
        if ((ULONG64)fsi.EndOfFile.QuadPart - 1 < 0x100000)
        {
            if (PBYTE buf = new UCHAR[fsi.EndOfFile.LowPart + FIELD_OFFSET(ICONDIR, Reserved)])
            {
                PBYTE pb = buf + FIELD_OFFSET(ICONDIR, Reserved);

                if (ReadFile(hFile, pb, fsi.EndOfFile.LowPart, &fsi.EndOfFile.LowPart, 0) &&
                    IsValidIcon((ICONDIR*)buf, fsi.EndOfFile.LowPart) + FIELD_OFFSET(ICONDIR, Reserved))
                {
                    ULONG cch = 0;
                    PSTR psz = 0;
                    while (CryptBinaryToStringA(pb, fsi.EndOfFile.LowPart, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64|CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF, psz, &cch))
                    {
                        if (psz)
                        {
                            *pcch = cch, *ppsz = psz, psz = 0, f = TRUE;
                            break;
                        }

                        if (!(psz = new CHAR[cch]))
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (psz)
                    {
                        delete [] psz;
                    }

                }
                delete [] buf;
            }
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return f;
}
```

for test icon:

```
ULONG cch;
PSTR psz;
if (mi(L"...ico", &psz, &cch))
{
    HICON hi = LoadIcon(psz, cch, 48, 48);
    delete [] psz;

    if (hi)
    {
        TASKDIALOGCONFIG TaskConfig = { 
            sizeof(TaskConfig), 0, 0, TDF_USE_HICON_MAIN, TDCBF_CLOSE_BUTTON, 0, {hi}
        };
        TaskDialogIndirect(&TaskConfig, 0, 0, 0);

        DestroyIcon(hi);
    }
}
```